# How do I horizontally center my nav bar without manually setting the width?

Tags: html, css

I have the following nav bar:

```
<header>
  <h1>Blah blah</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a>
      <li><a href="#">bar</a>
      <li><a href="#">baz</a>
      <li><a href="#">zop</a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

How do I center it perfectly? I also have the following css:

```
header {
    background-color: #a4c9f3;
    text-align: center;
}
header nav {
    /* guessing this width works, but I don't want to do it manually */
    /* width: 24em; */
    display: inline-block;
}
header nav ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 6px;
    list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li a {
    padding: 9px 22px 4px 16px;
    background-color: #83b2e6;
}
```

As you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcjohnalds/YkZqj/3/), it's *almost* centered.

Comment: You don't properly close your `<li>` tags.

Comment: @destroydaworl li tags don't need to be closed according to w3c http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission

Comment: Alright, didn't know that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `ul` to  `width: 100%` and center the text, set your `li` as `display: inline`.
And display your anchors as inline-blocks:

CSS:

```
header {
    background-color: #a4c9f3;
    text-align: center;
}
header nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}
header nav ul li a {
    padding: 9px 22px 4px 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #83b2e6;
}
```

[**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/YkZqj/18/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the default padding/margin from ul and li elements, you can use a reset css stylesheet like Eric Meyer's reset or something like this:

```
header nav ul, header nav ul li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Demo working: http://jsfiddle.net/YkZqj/13/
CSS Reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/